# What operation is being done for this set of values?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, operator-theory

I have a table that looks like the following:

```
    A   B   C
A | B   A   C
B | A   C   A 
C | C   A   B
```

Some operation is being done between an element in the first row and an element in the first column but I don't know what it is. The table looks like a familiar operation but I can't quite remember. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are A, B and C just arbitrary elements without any special interpretations?

Comment: Yes they are arbitrary elements but a mapping could exist between them and some other set of elements.

Comment: Whatever the operation is, it is commutative but not associative.